# Tomcat hangs at "Deploying web application directory..."

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, java

I am trying to setup Tomcat application server in an Ubuntu server. When I am trying to start tomcat server it hangs at deployment stage. If I try http://localhost:8080, its taking infinity time to load and nothing coming. There is no .war in webapps direcotry and I am just testing tomcat installation.

Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Tomcat version:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.61
Server built:   Mar 27 2015 12:03:56 UTC
Server number:  7.0.61.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.16.0-28-generic
Architecture:   i386
JVM Version:    1.7.0_79-b15
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Output when I tried to start Tomcat -

```
:~$ /opt/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/java7/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.61
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Mar 27 2015 12:03:56 UTC
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.61.0
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            3.16.0-28-generic
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          i386
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /opt/java7/jre
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat7
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat7
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat7/endorsed
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat7
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat7
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat7/temp
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the  java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1159 ms
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInterna
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.61
May 14, 2015 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
```

Comment: Take a look in http://serverfault.com/questions/655616/tomcat7-hangs-on-deploying-apps

Comment: Looks like a problem with your application. Look at the localhost logfile in /var/log/tomcat eg localhost.2015-05-14.log